# how to convert lua logitech script to xml razer mouses script

Tags: xml, lua, logitech-gaming-software

i want to convert my lua code to xml code for razer mouses can someone help me with that?

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("numlock")then
if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
repeat
MoveMouseRelative(-2, 3)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(2, -2)
Sleep(10)
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end 
end
end
```

```
    i want to convert it to xml please help me
```

Comment: I think the quickest way would be to record a macro, then opening the macro to adapt the 4 relative positions manually. I failed to find a proper documentation.

Comment: Please explain what this script does.